# Binding a nullable datetime within WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datetime, binding

I have a wpf application in which I had this property to bind to a **datepicker**

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dpc_date_engagement { get; set; }
```

So I add a converter :

```
 public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return ((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString();
        return String.Empty;
    }

       public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           string strValue = value.ToString();
           DateTime resultDateTime;
           return DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime) ? resultDateTime : value;
       }
   }
```

**In XAML file :**

```
                     <DatePicker >
                                <DatePicker.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="dpc_date_engagement" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <converter:DateConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </DatePicker.Text>
                            </DatePicker>
```

The problem is when the date is null, the displayed text is 1/1/0001.

- How can I fix my code to display an empty string instead of 01/01/0001, for null values?

Comment: What about breakpoint in converter?

Comment: @YuriDorokhov For null values ,it gives me value = `01/01/0001 00:00:00` in the method convert

Comment: have you tried setting a style that sets text to "" when value is null ?

Comment: have a data trigger on value x:null and set text to "".. should work . I haven't tried though. lemme know if you implement

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Obviously your Nullable<DataTime> does not hold a `null` value, but `DateTime.MinValue` (or a default-constructed DateTime) instead. If it would hold a null value, the cast expression `(DateTime)value` would throw on exception.

Comment: @Clemens That's true, plz post your comment as an answer , thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nullable `value` passed to your converter is not itself `null`, even if it holds a `null` value (it can't even be null, because it is a struct and therefore not nullable).

So instead of comparing `value` to `null`, you'll have to cast it to `Nullable<Datetime>` and then check its `HasValue` property.

Moreover, you seem to have something like `DateTime.MinValue` in your bound property instead of `null`. So you should check against that, too:

```
public object Convert(...)
{
    var nullable = (Nullable<DateTime>)value;

    if (nullable.HasValue && nullable.Value > DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        return nullable.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: For null values `nullable = 01/01/0001 00:00:00` , so I have the same result

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way I've been found to handle **nullable** **DateTime** field using in a **DatePicker** is setting **TargetNullValue=''**

In XAML file:

```
<DatePicker Text={Binding dpc_date_engagement, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} />
```

Comment: Wow that really is the best solution. I tried hours on binding to SelectedDate with converting the Text Binding. But always got others problem. Binding the DateTime Property like this to the Text also solves the Problem that the Binding to SelectedDate only updates on LostFocus. Thanks a lot

Comment: can we set a text in the `TargetNullValue`? e.g. TargetNullValue="no selected date"?

Answer (score 1):

For me I actually had to add the `Mode=TwoWay` attribute to my DatePicker. Now its working perfectly with Nullable Dates:

NullableDateConverter.cs

```
public class NullableDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is DateTime?))
            return string.Empty;

        var ndt = (DateTime?)value;
        if (ndt.HasValue)
            return ndt.Value.ToShortDateString();
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var dateTime) ? dateTime : value;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Path.To.The.Converter.Folder"

...

<Window.Resources>
    <conv:NullableDateConverter x:Key="dateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<DatePicker Text="{Binding SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}"/>
```